# In the "Enderal" story mod, is the player Tealor's abandoned child?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, enderal-the-shards-of-order

In the standalone story expansion to "Skyrim"- "[Enderal](http://sureai.net/games/enderal/?lang=en)" the main character is a halfbreed, child of two human races.

In one of the "visions from family home" you can see your "daddy" beating your mother accusing her of being unfaithful - we never actually see her face, but at least in my case my father is displayed as a pale-skinned (like most citizens of Enderal), while my character was dark skinned half-Arazealer.

Now, the back story of the paladin Tealor (the leader of the Order and main NPC of the game) is that after the death of Light-Born (immortal mages worshipped as gods, that Order was supposed to protect) he was imprisoned by his son, that was leading the revolution against theocracy.

But then towards the end of the game, we find bit more information about Tealor's child:

> Tealor had an affair with one of the Light-Born and after she got pregnant he decided to leave the child with one of her servants, to avoid the scandal, that would cost him his position in the Order.

Since again, we can't clearly see the face of Tealor lover's face, we don't know what race she really was.

So my question is: Has Tealor had two children, one abandoned with a servant, one leading the revolution or was it one and the same child? And if the former is true, was the player that abandoned child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research on the lore of the Enderal mod, it looks like Grandmaster Tealor Arantheal only had one child. The child is **not** the player.

> The child is revealed during the story to be Narathzul.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/enderal/comments/4tbmrx/request_for_a_short_summary_of_nehrims_story/d5g8ctc/?) is a good summary of the plot (spoilers present, naturally). The most relevant takeaway from the summary is this line:

> When [the Player and Narathzul] try to kill Tyr and Irlanda it is revealed that Narathzul is actually the son of Irlanda and Tealor.

Additionally, [Grandmaster Tealor Arantheal's wikia page](http://en.wiki.sureai.net/Enderal:Grandmaster_Tealor_Arantheal) says that he only has one child.